# 'string indices must be integers' error with this JSON dict

Tags: python, json

I have a dictionary with a single item in it created using `json.loads()`. The data structure looks like this:

```
{"teamId":96}
```

When I attempt to access the dictionary value by using the following:

```
mydict = mydict[u'teamId']
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\counter.py", line 65, in <module>
    print home_team[u'teamId']
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Can anyone explain to me what the issue is here? The code looks like it should work to me.

Thanks

Comment: It means that `home_team` is a string, not a dict like you said it is. Without knowing where/how you assign a value `home_team`, that's all one can say.

Comment: Looks like you haven't actually loaded the JSON string.

Comment: Are you really sure that you did `mydict = json.loads('{"teamId":96}')`?

Comment: thanks for the replies all. my mistake, i had not used json.loads() in this instance, when i thought i had.

Answer (score 1):

You need [`json.dumps(you_file)`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/json.html#json.dumps) :

```
json.loads(json.dumps(your_file))
```